# CMake: Include directory for local static library

Tags: cmake, static-libraries

I have a static library in my project, lets call it `libcommon`, and I am including a header file from this library `#include <libcommon/common.h>`, not the angular brakets, not upper quotes. How can I configure CMakeLists.txt so that it find the include?

Assume the directory structure is like this:

```
-- root/
    \-- src/
    |   |-- libcommon/common.h
    |   \-- main/main.c
    \-- CMakeLists.txt
```

I tried:

```
include_directories (... src)
```

and:

```
include_directories (... ${main_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
```

but the libcommon/common.h was not found.

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out while writing the question:

Instead of using just include_directories, I had to use target_include_directories:

```
target_include_directories(main PRIVATE src)
```

or:

```
target_include_directories(main PRIVATE ${main_SOURCE_DIR}/src)
```